# how to get the values from <malt-list-item> in angular8?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my project, I have a mat-list item. so when I click any items I want to get that item value. I tried the below method but it's not working for me.
how to get that value?
My HTML:

```
 <mat-list role="list"  ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="jobSort">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let jobSort of jobSortBy" (click)="sortBy()" [value]="jobSort">{{ jobSort | translate}}>
   </mat-list-item>
 </mat-list>
```

my enum file:

```
export enum JobSortBy {
    NAME = 'NAME', CREATED_AT = 'CREATED_AT', BUDGET = 'BUDGET' , SIZE = 'SIZE'}
```

My ts file:

```
get jobSortBy(): String[]{
    return Object.values(JobSortBy).filter(key => isNaN(key));
}
```

can you please anyone help me to get this value

Answer (score 0):

First your `enum` name is `JobSortBy` but you are doing looping on `jobSortBy` instead of `JobSortBy`.

On `click` event you are calling `sortBy()` instead of `jobSortBy()` . From you code it looks like you should call `jobSortBy()` . Well if `sortBy()` method is already existing then no need.

Instead of  `[value]="jobSort"` you should use  `[value]="jobSort.Name"`

`[(ngModel)]="jobSort"`  Make sure you have `jobSort`  in your typescript

So here is your improved code

**HTML**

```
<mat-list role="list"  ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="jobSort">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let jobSort of jobSortBy" (click)="jobSortBy()" 
   [value]="jobSort.Name">
          {{ jobSort | translate}}>
   </mat-list-item>
 </mat-list>
```

**Typescript**

```
jobSort = "";   //Assign it value as per your requirement

export enum JobSortBy {
         NAME = 'NAME', 
         CREATED_AT = 'CREATED_AT', 
         BUDGET = 'BUDGET' , 
         SIZE = 'SIZE'
}

get JobSortBy(): String[]{   
    return Object.values(JobSortBy).filter(key => isNaN(key));
}
```